# how to suppress leading 0 in javascript to generate properly formatted url? (all attempts have generated typedef errors)

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql

I'm forming a URL which can't have leading zeroes in the dist GET parameter filled with distance[i].

```
trr2.innerHTML= "<b><a href='join.php?id="+idO[i]+"&dist="+distance[i] +"&category="+category[i]+"&min="+min[i]+"&max="+max[i]+"'>Join this deal</a>";
```

The link generated in this prints distance[i] with a leading 0 and then decimal point when the number is less than zero, for example "...&dist=0.6..." which in turn is causing errors with the postgresql call I generate with this expression. I tried all of the following to either remove the leading 0 from the number or cast the number explicitly to a number in hopes that this would suppress the leading zero:

```
    var dis = distance[i]
...following by any of these....
    var disNN = dis.replace("0", ""); //there will only be 0's in the lead, I know all submitted values, so this expression won't cause other problems
    var disNN = dis.replace(/^0+/, '');
    var disNN = number(dis)
```

Any of these, when included in my code, generate the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This seems like it should be so simple....how can I get rid of that leading zero for values that are between 0 and 1?

Also, the array is generated from php with a call like this:

```
var distance = <?php echo json_encode($distance);?>;
```

in case that's relevant. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is in the message you are seeing

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I'm not too sure how distance[i] is being instantiated; but my guess is that it is an int, not a string, so it does not have any of the built in string functions (like .replace).

You could try this:

```
var dis = distance[i].toString();
```

Please take care to make sure distance[i] isn't null, or 'toString fails and you're back to sqaure one.

Comment: You were right. Thanks much but I've got to register a gripe to the universe in particular that js adds leading zeroes in the case that it's a number type to begin with!

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove the leading zeroes using the php function [ltrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) and pass the distances well formatted to the javascript that generates the urls.

Usage:

```
$str = ltrim($str, '0');// Remove leading 0's
echo ltrim(00000.1, '0');// echoes .1
```

Comment: The problem originates from the json encoding echo statement to javascript. The array is numeric in php - there are no leading zeroes if I print the array from php.

Comment: As far as I know, if you json_encode(.1) it outputs ".1"

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I'm not sure what else is going on. I did a print_r on my array before json_encoding it to javascript, and that shows no leading zeroes. The only other code is what I pasted in my question.